# Using Javascript to solve form options

Tags: javascript

I have a booking form, where users will get a discount for the more weeks they book. For example, one week costs £940, two weeks cost £1,410 and three weeks cost £1,880.

The checkbox options on the form are:

Week 1
Week 2
Week 3

So if a user just chooses "Week 1" it will cost £940. If a user chooses "Week 1" and "Week 2" it will cost £14,10 and so on.

I think javascript should be able to solve this, but am not sure how it can be done with variables. I've thought something along the lines of the following for the html:

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="CourseDatesFee0" value="940.00 " name="form[CourseDatesFee][]">
        <label for="CourseDatesFee0"> Week 1 (6-11 Apr)</label>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="CourseDatesFee1" value="940.00 " name="form[CourseDatesFee][]">
        <label for="CourseDatesFee1"> Week 2 (12-18 Apr)</label>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="CourseDatesFee2" value="940.00 " name="form[CourseDatesFee][]">
        <label for="CourseDatesFee2"> Week 3 (19-25 Jul)</label>
</p>    

<p>Once your dates are selected, please press the button below to confirm</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Confirm your dates</button>
```

Comment: Make an HTML front end with some input boxes, have a button that will start a function.  That function should grab handles or just the flat values from the input boxes, do some operations and then spit the input out into another input box.

Comment: assuming there is a x% discount depending on how many weeks the user chose: add a function `checkDiscount` to each checkbox element. everytime a checkbox is clicked, it will loop through the checkboxes to check how many of them are checked. if one is checked, no discount, if 2 are checked (you can now make sure if the user chose N weeks in a row) x% of discount, if 3 are checked, y% and so on... the discount would be given to the total amount of money the user would pay without any discount. the amount of discount may be the output of a formula too (or a constant value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I have used the following Javascript to solve this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateTotal(){
        total = 0;

        if( (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee0').checked) || (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee1').checked) || (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee2').checked)  )
        total = 940.00;

        if( (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee0').checked) && (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee1').checked)  )
        total = 1410.00;

        else if ( (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee0').checked) && (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee2').checked)  )
        total = 1410.00;

        else if ( (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee1').checked) && (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee2').checked)  )
        total = 1410.00;

        if ( (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee0').checked) && (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee1').checked) && (document.getElementById('CourseDatesFee2').checked)  )
        total = 1880.00;

document.getElementById('TotalFees').value = total;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The radio button should have the values for each option. When the user clicks one of the radio buttons, then you get the `value` of the chosen `input` (the one that is checked). Or if you need the `value` of the radios for something else, you could use `data` attributes.

Comment: I actually kind of disagree with this from a data design point of view, personally.  Weeks should capture weeks, not price.  Even if there is no other use for weeks right now, that doesn't mean that there won't be in the future, and then he would have even more updates needed for his code.  Keeping weeks and price separate, but mapped together avoids this.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I just saw the updates to your question (funny, I assumed that it was a trip . . . never occurred to me that it would be a class   :D   ).  Looks like your sample code would still work with the code that I posted, though (even if some of the values need to be changed).

---

I'd recommend a JS object that pairs the number of weeks with the price . . . something like this:

```
var oPriceData = {
    "1 week": 940,
    "2 weeks": 1410,
    "3 weeks": 1880
}
```

Then the HTML would be something like this (**note:** I HIGHLY recommend a radio button group [or even a dropdown], instead of checkboxes, since that will restrict the user to a single choice):

```
<form id="frmTripInfo">
    <input id="cbTripLength_1week" name="cbTripLength" type="radio" value="1 week" />
    <label for="cbTripLength_1week">1 week</label><br/>

    <input id="cbTripLength_2weeks" name="cbTripLength" type="radio" value="2 weeks" />
    <label for="cbTripLength_2weeks">2 weeks</label><br/>

    <input id="cbTripLength_3weeks" name="cbTripLength" type="radio" value="3 weeks" />
    <label for="cbTripLength_3weeks">3 weeks</label><br/>
</form>
```

At this point, once the user has selected a value, you find the matching price from the object, like this . . . first, get the selected value:

```
var sTripOptions = document.forms.frmTripInfo.elements.cbTripLength;
var sTripLength = "";

for (var i = 0; i < sTripOptions.length; i++) {
    var currOption = sTripOptions[i];
    if (currOption.checked) {
        sTripLength = currOption.value;
    }
}
```

Then get the price from the object, using the selected value, like this:

```
var iTripPrice = oPriceData[sTripLength];
```

There is further logic that needs to be done (what event will trigger the price update, what happens if a week length isn't in the object, etc.), but this is the base logic that you would need.

There are several advantages to this approach:

1. You maintain the separation of the data . . . weeks are weeks and price is price.
2. The object can be used for other purposes . . . for example, if this data was provided dynamically (i.e., from a back-end system), you could actually set up the radio buttons/dropdown on the fly, with JavaScript (using the values in the object) .
3. The object is pretty easily expandable to add more trips, or extra data, if you think you will need that information.  For example:

> ```
> var oTripData = [
>     "trip1": {
>          "1 week": {
>              "displayText": "8 Days/7 Nights",
>              "price": 940
>          },
>         "2 weeks": {
>              "displayText": "15 Days/14 Nights",
>              "price": 1410
>          },
>          "3 weeks": {
>              "displayText": "22 Days/21 Nights",
>              "price": 1880
>          }
>      },
>      "trip2": {
>          "5 days": {
>              "displayText": "5 Days/4 Nights",
>              "price": 640
>          },
>          "1 week": {
>              "displayText": "8 Days/7 Nights",
>              "price": 1030
>          }
>      },
>      "trip3": {
>          "2 weeks": {
>              "displayText": "15 Days/14 Nights",
>              "price": 1210
>          },
>          "3 weeks": {
>              "displayText": "22 Days/21 Nights",
>              "price": 1680
>          },
>          "4 weeks": {
>              "displayText": "28 Days/27 Nights",
>              "price": 2260
>          }
>      }
> ]
> ```

Of course, if your data structure changes after you've coded the page, you would need to update the code, so you probably want to think ahead about the data requirements, and design the data structure and initial code, accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the very thought out and in-depth answer.  I have a question though, how do I then display the price once the selection has been made?

Comment: NP . . . happy to help.   :)   As for displaying the price, there are many ways that you could do that . . . and update a text input using something like this: `document.forms.frmTripInfo.elements.txtTripPrice.value = iTripPrice;`, or, if you don't want to use an input, you could have an empty `<div>` tag with an `id` (let's use "totalCost"), and update the value there, like this: `document.getElementById("totalCost").textContent = iTripPrice;` (or `.innerText`, if you want to support IE before IE9).